# Al hacer un ng test en angular me lanza este error TS2569: Type 'Map<unknown, unknown>' is not an array type or a string type

Tags: angular, typescript

Como se comenta en el titulo al intentar hacer un ng test me arroga ese error , buscando en la web me dicen que la solucion es: "downlevelIteration": true, pero sigue sin funcionar.

```
this.listadoAnniosTemporadas = [...new Map(this.listadoSemanas.map(item => [item[1], item])).values()];
```

esa es la linea que genera el error.

[image: Imagen del error]

Comment: Que es valor que quieres obtener desde `listadoSemanas`?

Comment: Ya se soluciono con un "downlevelIteration": true lo estaba ubicando mal , gracias por tu respuesta